# Redux state variable undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

There have been quite a few similar questions raised here but I couldn't find the answer to my problem.

Here is my React component:

```
class MyTransitPage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPassengerProfile();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.passenger.pid}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  return {
    passenger: state.transit.passenger
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPassengerProfile })(MyTransitPage)
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    passenger: {}
};

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("reducer ");
    console.log(action.payload);
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'GET_PASSENGER_PROFILE':
            return { ...state, passenger: action.payload};

        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

When I do console.log in the reducer I can see that the payload is there:

```
"passenger": Object {
[20:57:55]     "createdAt": "2019-02-10T13:02:40.897Z",
[20:57:55]     "objectId": "YKzeH2Nh3C",
[20:57:55]     "pid": "iwKHqfCQSu",
[20:57:55]     "updatedAt": "2019-02-10T13:02:40.897Z",
[20:57:55]   },
```

But when I try to access {this.props.passenger.pid} in the component, I get pid as undefined. I can't find where the problem is. Where did I get it wrong?

EDIT: 
Root reducer:

```
export default combineReducers({
    auth: AuthenticationReducer,
    transit: TransitReducer
});
```

EDIT2: Action:

```
export const getPassengerProfile = () => {
    const currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    const currentUserId = currentUser._getId()

    const Passenger = Parse.Object.extend('Passenger');
    const query = new Parse.Query(Passenger);
    query.equalTo("pid", currentUserId);

    return (dispatch) => {
        query.first().then(response => {
            dispatch ({
                type: 'GET_PASSENGER_PROFILE',
                payload: response
            });      
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: As a sanity check, I would also console.log() action.type (above the switch statement). It's possible that the payload is what you expect, but maybe there's a typo in the type value, so your state isn't actually being updated.

Comment: hi @vm909 it comes as GET_PASSENGER_PROFILE

Comment: What do you see when you log state.transit before returning from mapStateToProps?

Comment: When I do console.log(this.props.passenger); in my render function I get the Object {
[21:55:09]   "createdAt": "2019-02-10T13:02:40.897Z",
[21:55:09]   "objectId": "YKzeH2Nh3C",
[21:55:09]   "pid": "iwKHqfCQSu",
[21:55:09]   "updatedAt": "2019-02-10T13:02:40.897Z",
[21:55:09] }

Comment: I think I found the answer. I used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) on the action.payload, which seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` on the action.payload, which seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this.props.getPassengerProfile()` in the componentDidMount which means the component is already mounted and rendered before the state is populated from that value. I would just add a check in your render so it doesn't error out and then when it does get there it should show properly. Like this:

```
render() {
  //console.log(this.props.transit);
  console.log(this.props);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{this.props.passenger ? this.props.passenger.pid : ''}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't get an error, in the screen. The screen remains empty, even though I can see the value in 'pid' from the console.log. But the value on the screen never appears and if I console.log the 'pid' parameter it comes back as undefined.

Comment: Ah, so from your console log it may look like your payload structure is actually `{payload: passenger: {}}` instead of just `{payload: {}}`. Maybe that is the issue and you need to use `action.payload.passenger` in your reducer. Seeing the `getPassengerProfile` might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @ageoff I added the action to the question.